# Rounded corners on inside in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

Is there an options to round the corners on inside like in the picture? I have tried with `CutCornerShape` but it cuts them straight[image].

Answer (score 0):

thy something like this

```
@Composable
private fun DrawTicketPathWithArc() {
    Canvas(modifier = canvasModifier) {

        val canvasWidth = size.width
        val canvasHeight = size.height

        // Black background
        val ticketBackgroundWidth = canvasWidth * .8f
        val horizontalSpace = (canvasWidth - ticketBackgroundWidth) / 2

        val ticketBackgroundHeight = canvasHeight * .8f
        val verticalSpace = (canvasHeight - ticketBackgroundHeight) / 2

        // Get ticket path for background
        val path1 = ticketPath(
            topLeft = Offset(horizontalSpace, verticalSpace),
            size = Size(ticketBackgroundWidth, ticketBackgroundHeight),
            cornerRadius = 20.dp.toPx()
        )
        drawPath(path1, color = Color.Black)

        // Dashed path in foreground
        val ticketForegroundWidth = ticketBackgroundWidth * .95f
        val horizontalSpace2 = (canvasWidth - ticketForegroundWidth) / 2

        val ticketForegroundHeight = ticketBackgroundHeight * .9f
        val verticalSpace2 = (canvasHeight - ticketForegroundHeight) / 2

        // Get ticket path for background
        val path2 = ticketPath(
            topLeft = Offset(horizontalSpace2, verticalSpace2),
            size = Size(ticketForegroundWidth, ticketForegroundHeight),
            cornerRadius = 20.dp.toPx()
        )
        drawPath(
            path2,
            color = Color.Red,
            style = Stroke(
                width = 2.dp.toPx(),
                pathEffect = PathEffect.dashPathEffect(
                    floatArrayOf(20f, 20f)
                )
            )
        )
    }
}
```

check this [page](https://github.com/SmartToolFactory/Jetpack-Compose-Tutorials#6-1-3-canvas-paths)

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution which looks like that

```
@Composable
private fun DrawDashLine() {
val pathEffect = PathEffect.dashPathEffect(floatArrayOf(12f, 10f), 0f)
Canvas(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()) {
    drawLine(
        color = Color.Black,
        strokeWidth = 3f,
        start = Offset(0f, 0f),
        end = Offset(size.width, 0f),
        pathEffect = pathEffect
    )
    drawCircle(
        color = Color.Black,
        center = Offset(x = 1f, y = 2f),
        radius = 20f
    )
    drawCircle(
        color = Color.Black,
        center = Offset(x = size.width, y = 2f),
        radius = 20f
    )
}
}
```

The background must be black, and the front is white and the round circles just come above the white.